# PInvokeStackImbalance was detected when manually running Xna Content pipeline

Tags: c#, xna

So I m running this code

```cs
    static readonly string[] PipelineAssemblies =
        {
            "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.FBXImporter" + XnaVersion,
            "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.XImporter" + XnaVersion,
            "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.TextureImporter" + XnaVersion,
            "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.EffectImporter" + XnaVersion,
            "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.XImporter" + XnaVersion,
            "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.AudioImporters" + XnaVersion,
            "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.VideoImporters" + XnaVersion,

        };
```

more code in between .....

```cs
        // Register any custom importers or processors.
        foreach (string pipelineAssembly in PipelineAssemblies)
        {
            _buildProject.AddItem("Reference", pipelineAssembly);
        }
```

more code in between .....

```cs
        var execute = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => submission.ExecuteAsync(null, null), cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        var endBuild = execute.ContinueWith(ant => BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.EndBuild());

        endBuild.Wait();
```

Basically trying to build the content project with code ... this works well if you remove XImporter, AudioIMporters and VideoImporters but with those I get the following error:

PInvokeStackImbalance was detected
Message: A call to PInvoke function 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline!Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.UnsafeNativeMethods+AudioHelper::GetFormatSize' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

A StackTrace
[image: StackTrace]

Things I've tried:

1. turn unsafe code on
2. adding a lot of logging (the dll is found in case you are wondering)
3. different wav and Mp3 files (just in case)
4. Building synchronously

UPDATE: there is not just one error, but a few similar ones that point to different methods
Will update...
UPDATE 2: This problem might be related to the target I m using to build the content project.

Comment: Hey there! It's been almost a year and your question appears too localized. If you've found an answer, maybe you should post it, or if you think the question won't help any future visitors, maybe you should remove it?

Comment: HI there. Well actually I haven't found a solution. Do you want me to reply saying there is no solution? In the end we got away with not fixing this because the project changed to use an external audio engine